# How to set individual sensitive content hide in android 9

Tags: 9.0-pie

Before using Android 9 I was able to set individual sensitive hide content on lock screen rule app by app. Something like, globally I selected Show All notification on the lock screen and then go to the specific app and set hide sensitive content on the lock screen. 
In android 9 stock android, I can do this, but the individual settings do not work, it still keeps showing sensitive contents on the lock screen. More specifically, when I am using WhatsApp or Messenger, It displays the message content on the lock screen even though I have set hide sensitive content on the lock screen. Is that a bug?

Comment: AFAIK, since Android 8.0 Oreo, each app can have multiple notification channels for different types of notification. Have you checked the setting for each channel?

Comment: How can I check this?